# Why a SQL Server join is taking too long to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-performance

I am populating a temporary table with data, below is the definition of my temp table.

```
DECLARE @PurgeFilesList TABLE
(
    JobFileID BIGINT,
    ClientID INT,
    StatusID INT,
    IsPurgeSuccessfully BIT,
    ReceivedDate DATETIME,
    FilePath VARCHAR(2000),
    StatementPath VARCHAR(2000)
)
```

Insert logic to populate temp table, after this I am making an additional join with a table named `Account`:

```
SELECT 
    JobFileID,
    PFL.ClientID,
    StatusID,
    IsPurgeSuccessfully,
    ReceivedDate,
    CASE 
       WHEN FilePath IS NULL THEN StatementPath 
       ELSE FilePath 
    END 'FilePath'
FROM 
    @PurgeFilesList PFL
INNER JOIN 
    Account(NOLOCK) A ON ISNULL(PFL.ClientID, 0) = ISNULL(A.ClientID, 0) 
                      AND A.HoldStatementPurge = 0
```

But, this join is taking too much time. Although total number of rows in Account table is less than 5000.

`Account` table schema:

```
Column_name         Type    Computed    Length
-----------------------------------------------
AccountID           bigint      no        8
AccountNumber       varchar     no        32
PrimaryCustomerName varchar     no        100
LastName            varchar     no        100
ClientName          varchar     no        32
BankID              varchar     no        32
UpdatedDate         datetime    no        8
IsPurged            bit         no        1
PurgeDate           datetime    no        8
ClientID            int         no        4
HoldStatementPurge  bit         no        1
```

Kindly let me know, if any other info is required.

Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing NOLOCK ?

Comment: How many rows are there in `@PurgeFilesList`? Table variables are always a bit dangerous, performance-wise, since the query optimizer will always assume just a single row (which can have severe negative impacts on execution plan, if there are a lot more rows in the table variable)

Comment: @HoneyBadger updated my question. Please see the execution plan.

Comment: @FranCerezo yes, no luck.

Comment: @marc_s table variable is having less than 2000 records.

Comment: That's quite a few rows for a table variable! Is that whole operation something you do on a regular basis? If so, I'd strongly recommend to create an intermediary table (an actual table - not a table variable) and fill your data into that intermediary table. Such a table can be **indexed** to improve performance (while a table variable cannot)

Comment: What indexes are there on table `Account`? You seem to only need the `A.ClientId` for joining, and the `A.HoldStatementPurge` in your `WHERE` clause - yet in the execution plan, there's a very costly full table scan on `Account`. Is there an index just on these two columns, possibly? Is `ClientId` in `Account` nullable or not?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using any column from `Account` so, i would use `EXISTS` :

```
select fl.JobFileID, fl.ClientID, fl.StatusID, 
       fl.IsPurgeSuccessfully, fl.ReceivedDate, 
       isnull(FilePath, StatementPath) as FilePath
from @PurgeFilesList fl
where fl.ClientID is null or
      exists (select 1 
              from Account a 
              where a.clientid = fl.clientid and a.HoldStatementPurge = 0
             );
```

For the performance, index would be helpful on `Account(clientid,HoldStatementPurge)` & same as table variable. Just make sure your table variable has some smaller amount of data if that is not the case then you will need to use temporary tables & provide appropriate index on that table.

Answer (score 1):

Your Account schema is missing nullable yes/no information. Having said that I assume Account.ClientID is not nullable so `ISNULL(PFL.ClientID, 0) = A.ClientID` would do too. Anyway.

My guess is you are missing a couple of well placed indexes here such as:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Account_ClientID_HoldStatementPurge ON Account(ClientID, HoldStatementPurge)
```

Or just

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Account_ClientID ON Account(ClientID)
```

I'd say try creating both while checking the query plan first.

Also, you might want to use a Temporary Table (`CREATE TABLE #TempTable ...`) for this scenario instead of a Table Variable (`DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ...`) so you can apply an additional index to speed up things:

```
CREATE TABLE #PurgeFilesList 
(
    JobFileID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientID INT,
    StatusID INT,
    IsPurgeSuccessfully BIT,
    ReceivedDate DATETIME,
    FilePath VARCHAR(2000),
    StatementPath VARCHAR(2000)
)

CREATE INDEX #IX_PurgeFilesList_ClientID ON #PurgeFilesList(ClientID)
```

The reason for this is that it is not possible to create non-clustered indexes on Table Variables (only a primary key is permitted).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the record size in table `@PurgeFilesList`.
try to use Temp Table  instead of Table Variable.